# why is the output in lottery code isn't working?

Tags: c#, random, input, int, compare

I'm supposed to make a code in c# (microsoft visual studio 2017) that lets the user input six numbers, and then compare them to an array of six randomly generated numbers(with no duplicates).

If the user has one match, he's supposed to get a message saying he had one match, and different messages for two or three matches, and so on.

This is what I got so far:

```
static bool isValueInArray(int value, int[] a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] == value)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int min = 0;
        int max = 6;
        Random randnum = new Random();//random number generator
        int[] numbers = new int[6];// generates six numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = randnum.Next(min, max);//sets the numbers between 0 to 6
            if(isValueInArray( i, numbers))
            {
                numbers[i] = randnum.Next(min, max);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello and Welcome to our little game of lottery! lets see just how much luck you got!"); // greetings and instructions
            Console.WriteLine("You'll now get to choose 6 different numbers between 0 to 6 to play with.");
            Console.WriteLine("Go ahead and type them in.");

            int[] lottery = new int[6];

            for (int i = 0; i < lottery.Length; i++)
            {
                lottery[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // array to catch six numbers input
                if (lottery[i] > 6)//checking if the numbers fit between 0 and 6
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("whoops! the number you enetered isn't in range! please try again ^^");
                    break;
                }

                int x = 6;
                for (int a = 0; a < lottery.Length; a++)
                {
                    for (int b = 0; b < numbers.Length; b++)
                    {
                        if (lottery[a] == numbers[b])
                        {
                            a++;
                            x--;
                            if (x == 6)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("six match");
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (x == 5)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("five match");
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (x == 4)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("four match");
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (x == 3)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("three match");
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (x == 2)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("two match");
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (x == 1)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("one match");
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (FormatException)// checking if the input is in char format
        {
            Console.WriteLine("only numbers please!");
        }
    }
```

My problem is with the output. The program seems to go over all of the "else if" options and print all of them, instead of picking and printing just one of them.

Comment: Count the number of matches first, then print the results. (Move the if/else block that prints the results to after the `for` loops that calc the results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to rearrange the code blocks in a way to get user input first, calculate the number of matches first, then display results as following code:

Note: Your approach to guarantee unique numbers in the randomly generated number ain't going to work as you expect to, you are passing "i" where you may want to pass "numbers[i]" instead to the isValueInArray" function. Let aside the idea that you will always end with values 0-5 in the array since you want 6 numbers.

```
            int min = 0;
            int max = 6;
            Random randnum = new Random();//random number generator
            int[] numbers = new int[6];// generates six numbers
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                numbers[i] = randnum.Next(min, max);//sets the numbers between 0 to 6
                if (isValueInArray(i, numbers))
                {
                    numbers[i] = randnum.Next(min, max);
                }
            }

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello and Welcome to our little game of lottery! lets see just how much luck you got!"); // greetings and instructions
                Console.WriteLine("You'll now get to choose 6 different numbers between 0 to 6 to play with.");
                Console.WriteLine("Go ahead and type them in.");

                int[] lottery = new int[6];

                int x = 0;
                //read user numbers
                for (int i = 0; i < lottery.Length; i++)
                {
                    lottery[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // array to catch six numbers input
                    while (lottery[i] > 6)//checking if the numbers fit between 0 and 6
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("whoops! the number you enetered isn't in range! please try again ^^");
                        lottery[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // array to catch six numbers input
                    }
                }

                //count number of matches
                for (int a = 0; a < lottery.Length; a++)
                {
                    for (int b = 0; b < numbers.Length; b++)
                    {
                        if (lottery[a] == numbers[b])
                        {
                            //a++;
                            x++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //display results
                if (x == 6)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("six matches");
                }
                else if (x == 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("five matches");
                }
                else if (x == 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("four matches");
                }
                else if (x == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("three matches");
                }
                else if (x == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("two matches");
                }
                else if (x == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("one match");
                }

            }

            catch (FormatException)// checking if the input is in char format
            {
                Console.WriteLine("only numbers please!");
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have everything mixed together. Write out the steps:

1. Generate numbers
2. Get input from user
3. Count number of matches
4. Print results

Each step should be performed separately.

```
// These should be the min/max lottery numbers
int min = 1;
int max = 100;

int numberOfLotteryNumbers = 6;
// Renamed for clarity
int[] lotteryNumbers = new int[numberOfLotteryNumbers];
int[] userNumbers = new int[numberOfLotteryNumbers];

// Step 1 - generate numbers
for (int i = 0; i < lotteryNumbers.Length; i++) {
    int randomNumber;
    do {
       randomNumber = randnum.Next(min, max);
    } while (isValueInArray(randomNumber, lotteryNumbers));
    lotteryNumbers[i] = randomNumber;
}

// Step 2 - get numbers from user
for (int i = 0; i < lottery.Length; i++) {
    int userInput;
    do {
        userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    } while (userInput < min || userInput > max || isValueInArray(userInput, userNumbers));
    userNumbers[i] = userInput;
}

// Step 3 - calc matches
int matches = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < userNumbers.Length; i++) {
    if (isValueInArray(userNumbers[i], lotteryNumbers) {
        matches += 1;
    }
}

// Step 4 - print results
Console.WriteLine("There are {0} matches.", matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter to achieve your goal. Just increment counter value on match:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lottery.Length; i++)
{ 
  // .. 
  if (x == number)
  {
      counter++; 
      break;
  } 
  // ..
} 
Console.WriteLine("You have " + counter + " matches");
```